# RelativeLayout add rule "RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF" not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relativeLayout like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/parent" >

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the java code, I want to add a view to the left of the listview, but it didn't worked:

```
m_relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, m_listView.getId());
Button button2 = new Button(this);
button2.setText("I am button 2");
m_relativeLayout.addView(button2, layoutParams);
```

only if I set the listview to **alignParentRight**, it will work. Is this an android bug or  I'm missing something?

I always try `addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params)`, but it might only work in the linearlayout. So is there an normal solution to make the `RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF` work?

**EDIT**

I have tried `RelativeLayout.BELOW` and `RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF`, and they worked perfectly, so it means I don't have enough place to get the button? I tried to give more space, but it still not work.

I use Toshiba AT100 (1280*800) and landscape, so the space is enough. Test `below` and `right` just same as the `left`. I think If i put an control A in the relativelayout, then I add control B and decalare it's on the left of the control A, the result should be the control B will push the control A to its right, right?

Comment: Where does the view appear at?

Comment: The relativelayout is the mainview of the activity, and it has the space to add the button.

Comment: I actually mean, does the button just not appear, or appear in an inappropriate place?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I think If i put an control A in the relativelayout, then i add control B and declare it's on the left of the control A, the result should be the control B will push the control A to its right, right?

Your assumption is incorrect, the control A will not be pushed to the right unless you specified this with a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` rule. `RelativeLayout` places its children one one top of each other starting at the top-left corner of the screen if you don't specify placement rules for them. When you add the `View` A to the `RelativeLayout` without any rules(like `layout_alignParentRight`) it will be placed starting from the top-left corner of the screen. Then, when you add the `View` B, the rule `to_leftOf` will apply to this `View` position but this rule doesn't mean anything for the `View` A who will maintain its position on the screen. This will make `View` B to be place to the left of `View` A but outside of the screen as `View` A bounds start from the left border of the screen.

The `Button` will be placed to the left of the `ListView` when you use `layout_alignParentRight="true"` because there is now space to actually see the `Button`(it's not outside anymore). `addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params)` works in a `LinearLayout` because the `LinearLayout` arranges its children in a row or column(depending on orientation) so when you add a `View` at a specific position, it will push the other `Views` after it to the right or below(depending on orientation)(there is no relative positioning of the views in a `LinearLayout`, the only rule is that the children come one after the other).

Starting with the `ListView` without any rules set on it, here is an example on how to make the `Button` to appear on the left of the `ListView`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button button2 = new Button(this);
button2.setText("I am button 2");
button2.setId(1000);
m_relativeLayout.addView(button2, layoutParams);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) m_listView
            .getLayoutParams();
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, button2.getId());
```

The Button will be added as normal to the screen and it will appear starting from the top-left corner of the screen. Without the two lines from the code above the `Button` and `ListView` will overlap as this is the normal behavior of `RelativeLayout` for children without any rules on them. We then explicitly modify the position of the `ListView` to move it to the right(with the last two line from the code above).

Comment: I use Toshiba AT100 (1280*800) and landscape, so the space is enough Test `below` and `right` just same as the `left`. I think If i put an control A in the relativelayout, then i add control B and decalare it's on the left of the control A, the result should be the control B will push the control A to its right, right?

Comment: @dreamtale I misunderstood your question the first time. I've edited my answer, see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

If your variable names are indicative, it's because you are adding the widget to a LinearLayout, so tags for a RelativeLayout get ignored.

This line is the one I'm talking about:

```
m_linearLayout.addView(button2, layoutParams);
```

**EDIT**

You say `alignParentRight` works... the only difference there is that ot doesn't take an anchor parameter.  Perhaps `m_listView.getId()` isn't returning the proper id.  You could step through with the debugger and see if it's returning a proper value.

Maybe you could try calling the id specifically...

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.list);
```

Comment: You mean i should use linearlayout? Can you give me more details?

Comment: No, I mean you need to add a view to a RelativeLayout for RelativeLayout rules to work.  That view reference says `m_linearlayout`, which says to me you are trying to add the view to a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout.  Since you haven't shown where you set the `m_linearlayout` reference, I'm assuming you are using an appropriate name.  Unless you have `m_linearlayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.parent)` somewhere, in which case I'd say you've chosen a very poor reference name for your relative layout.

Comment: Sorry for that, I tried it in an before project, and just replace the `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and don't change the variable name. I have edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

To perform it, use predefined view **ID** or declare one. In **values folder** create **ids.xml** then add a **Item** like this:

```
<item name="imageViewID" type="id"/>
```

use this id in your code where you are creating new Instance of view like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout=new RelativeLayout(context);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setId(R.id.imageViewID);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(50, 50);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layout.addView(imageView, layoutParams);

TextView  textView = new TextView(context);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());
layout.addView(nameView, nameLayoutParams);
```

or we can directly use this function **View.generateViewId()** to perform the same. Like this:

```
imageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Comment: If your application supports lower 17 devices too, then use `ViewCompat.generateViewId()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have forgotten to add `m_listView` to the `RelativeLayout` or `m_listView`'s visibility would be `GONE`.

Can you please check for that?

Comment: As i can see you are setting layout params of relative layout but you are adding button in linear layout. Eiter use LinearLayout.LayoutParams rather than RelativeLayout.LayoutParams or call addView method of instance of the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

setId before align is called, especially for the new object view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom id and not a regular generated Android id (eg. `R.id.my_id`), make sure that the id is not equal to 0 (or negative), otherwise the rule will be ignored.