# Android dynamicly added button doesnt fit into layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with 5 `buttons` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#212121"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/menu"
android:gravity="center">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/main_menu"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/singleplayer_text"
        android:id="@+id/singleplayer_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="initializeGame"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/multiplayer_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/multiplayer_button"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:textColor="#212121" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/multiplayer_text"
        android:id="@+id/multiplayer_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/singleplayer_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:textColor="#212121" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/deck_name"
        android:id="@+id/deck_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/multiplayer_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/multiplayer_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/multiplayer_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:textColor="#212121" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/options_text"
        android:id="@+id/options_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deck_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:textColor="#212121" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/exit_text"
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/options_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:textColor="#212121" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Sometime in my game , i come to the point where i want to save it.And when it is saved, there should be another `button` added at my menu.

```
     resume= new Button(this);
     resume.setId((int) Math.random() * 10);
     resume.setText("Resume");
     resume.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
     resume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
     int margin = (int) (8 * scale + 0.5f);
     RelativeLayout main_menu = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_menu);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
     lp.setMargins(0, margin, 0,margin);
     main_menu.addView(resume, lp);
```

The problem is, that this new `button` `resume` covers the singleplayer `button`, but i want it on top of it and all buttons should still be centered.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.below_id);
```

Replace `below_id` with your specific id.

Comment: didnt know that, but i can only align it at the bottom, but not at the top

Comment: try `RelativeLayout.ABOVE` if you want to align top with id `R.id.singleplayer_button`

Answer (score 1):

> Adds a layout rule to be interpreted by the RelativeLayout. This
>   method should only be used for constraints that don't refer to another
>   sibling (e.g., CENTER_IN_PARENT) or take a boolean value (TRUE for
>   true or 0 for false). To specify a verb that takes a subject, use
>   addRule(int, int) instead.

According to your requirement **`doesnt fit into layout`** , You can remove

Remove this **First**  Then rectify your `addRule`

Read **[RelativeLayout add rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700273/relativelayout-add-rule-relativelayout-left-of-not-working)**

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: Ok i will try that,what you mean with rectifiy addRule?